# How to update entities through a relationship with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an **article** entity and a **tag** entity in my Symfony application. I have a nested form to edit and tag articles:

[image: I can add tags from inside the article form.]

When I add a new tag from this form, Doctrine tries to insert a new tag into the `Tag` table instead of a new relationship in the join table, i.e. `article_tag`, which results in a unique name constraint violation. To correct this, I've created a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), that fetches and returns any existing `Tag` object:

```
public function reverseTransform($name)
{
    //…

    return $this->om
        ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')
        ->findOneByName($name)
    ;
}
```

Unfortunately the application converts it back to string *(DBAL/Statement.php line 103)*, so Doctrine still initiates the same insert query. How can I prevent this? Where should I look for any error?

Pease check **ArticleType.php** and **TagType.php** in my question about [reusing existing entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22671294/868052) for my form's *Type files* and the two entities in my question about [avoiding duplicate entries with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21712710/868052) for the associations! I need to persist new tags (it works) and also select already persistent ones for new relations. I'm struggling with this task since a long time.

Comment: Please post your form's Type file & the your associations from both entities. Do you need to persist non existing tags as well or do you just need to select already persisted ones ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tags to be not mapped in `ArticleType`:

```
$builder->add('tags', 'text', array(
    //...
    'mapped' => false
));
```

Then you can get the value of the tags in you controller and you can find the existing entities to it. Then you can set these tags to your `Article`:

```
$data = $form->getData();
// now $data['tags'] are the tags
// ... Get the tags entities by Doctrine and set them to the article
$article->addTag($tag);
```

(Of course you have to implement the `addTag()` method in the `Article.php`.)

The you just simply `persist()` and then `flush()`, and the relations are correctly saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ArticleType.php:

```
    $builder->add('tags', new TagType(), array(
        //...
       'by_reference' => false,
    ));
```

For you add tag autocomplete check this bundle https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle